# How to use the UTF-8 Half Block to have two colors in one character block?

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8

I've seen the half block used in some terminal applications to fit two colors in one character block, and I want to recreate it in Python, but I can't figure out how to do it in Python because I can't find any tutorial/instructions online on how to actually do it. All i know currently is that its using these characters: ▀ ▄ but i don't know how it becomes one and turns to this █ on the terminal

[image: From https://github.com/sharkdp/pastel/] [image: From https://www.brow.sh/]

From https://github.com/sharkdp/pastel/ and https://www.brow.sh/

Comment: One color is the foreground – text – color, the other the background color.

Comment: Oh, that made sense. Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to usr2564301

> One color is the foreground – text – color, the other the background color. – usr2564301

This is my final code (using Pillow and ansicolors modules):

```
from PIL import Image
from colors import color

basewidth = 140
img = Image.open(str(input('Input File: ')))
wpercent = (basewidth/float(img.size[0]))
hsize = int((float(img.size[1])*float(wpercent)))
img = img.resize((basewidth,hsize), Image.ANTIALIAS)
img = img.convert('RGB')
width, height = img.size

for i in range(1, height, 2):
        line = ''
        for j in range(1, basewidth):
                ra, ga, ba = img.getpixel((j, i))
                rb, gb, bb = img.getpixel((j, i+1))
                line += color('\u2584', fg=(rb, gb, bb), bg=(ra, ga, ba))
        print(line)
```

And this is the result:

[image: Result]

I might change the basewidth to instead check the terminal width instead of having a fixed value